# Rails ERB Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, erb

I'm trying to add a validation to my Rails app in order to display an error message if the user goes to the wrong id. The project has reviews, if I go to `http://localhost:3000/reviews/:id that doesn't exist` the app crashes, I'd like to prevent the runtime error by displaying a message.

In the model, I got this validation:

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
    validates :id, presence: true 
end
```

Then, in the `reviews/show.html.erb` file, I'm trying this:

```
<% if @review.valid? %>
 <div class='review-header'>
  ....
 </div>
<% else %>
 <% @review.errors.objects.first.full_message %>
<% end %>
```

This is also the Reviews Controller:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_review, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
    before_action :authorize!, only: [:edit, :destroy]
    
    def index
      if params[:search]
        @reviews = Review.where("title like ?", "%#{params[:search]}%") 
      else
        @reviews = Review.all
      end
    end
  
    def new
      @review = Review.new
      @comment = Comment.new
      @comment.review_id = @review.id 
      #We need to declare the comments in the new action. 
    end
  
    def create
      @review = current_user.reviews.new(review_params)

      if @review.save
        redirect_to review_path(@review)
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end
  
    def show
      @comment = Comment.new 
      #We also need to declare the new comment in the show action. 
    end
  
    def edit
    end
  
    def update
      if @review.update(review_params)
        redirect_to review_path(@review)
      else  
        render 'edit'
      end  
    end
  
    def destroy
      @review.destroy
      redirect_to reviews_path   
    end
  
    private

      def set_review
        @review = Review.find_by(id: params[:id])
    end 
  
      def review_params
        params.require(:review).permit(:title, :content, :category_id, :search)
      end

      def authorize! 
        authorize @review #authorize method using the Pundit gem
    end 
end
```

However, my project keep crashing rather than showing a message. If there's any way I can make this work? Thanks.

Comment: Done, I updated the question and included the controller.

Comment: Your review will never be valid because it does not exist -- it will be null. You need to handle that. One course is to add a rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound your base application controller and redirect to a not found page.

Comment: Change `@review = Review.find_by(id: params[:id])` to `@review = Review.find(params[:id])` the later will raise a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception if the record is not found so your code doesn't just blow up with nil errors. Do not use `find_by` unless its actually a conditon where a nil is acceptable.

Comment: Another problem here the `new` action where you are doing `@comment.review_id = @review.id`.  Since `@review` is a new record it doesn't have an ID so you are just assigning nil. This is also an anti-pattern. Associate items by using assocations - not by manually assigning the id property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole setup of the question is actually broken.

You don't need to add a model validation for the id since ids are automatically generated by the database when you insert records. On most databases primary keys are also non-nullable. Adding the validation will actually break the model as will prevent you from saving records without manually assigning an id (bad idea).

Its also not the models job to verify that a record can be found in the controller. Instead your controller should use `find` so that it bails early if the record cannot be found:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_review, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authorize!, only: [:edit, :destroy]
 
  
  private

  def set_review
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])
  end 
end
```

This halts execution of the method and other callbacks and prevents the `NoMethodError`s that are bound to occur. There is no sense in continuing to process a request if the record that its supposed to CRUD doesn't exist.

By default Rails will handle an uncaught `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception by rendering a static HTML page located at `public/404.html` and returning a 404 status code. If you want to customize this on the controller level use `rescue_from`:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_review, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authorize!, only: [:edit, :destroy]
 
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :not_found
  
  private

  def set_review
    @review = Review.find(params[:id])
  end

  def not_found
    # renders app/reviews/not_found.html.erb
    render :not_found, 
      status: :not_found
  end 
end
```

Note that this should be done in different view. If you add a `<% if @review.present? %>` to your `reviews/show.html.erb` view you should get your Rails licence revoked as the views **one and only job** is to display the review.

You can also configure the responses on the application level with `config.exceptions_app`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that if the ID does not correspond to a review in the database, the `@review` object will be `nil`, and your line `if @review.valid?` will throw an error.

You need a different test, something like

```
<% if @review.present? %>
 <div class='review-header'>
  ....
 </div>
<% else %>
 Review does not exist.
<% end %>
```

Comment: This is basically just painting over the rot with more rot. Your view shouldn't be handling this.